# Plugin not updating in the plugin store from changelog updates

Tags: plugin-development, updates

I have a [custom plugin](https://github.com/hillholliday/Craft-User-Manual/) registered with [id.craftcms.com](https://id.craftcms.com/).

[image: id.craft.cms changelog screenshot]

The plugin store currently sees it at as 2.0.0, but I have since updated the plugin to 2.0.1 (and subsequently tried to force a silent 2.0.2 update) and noted so in my [changelog](https://github.com/hillholliday/Craft-User-Manual/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) but the plugin store is not seeing this update.

The contents of my changelog look like this:

```
# Release Notes for Craft User Manual

## 2.0.2 - 2019-02-27
### Updated
- Forcing new version for deprecation issues

## 2.0.1 - 2018-08-24
### Fixed
- Deprecation Issues

## 2.0.0 - 2018-08-24
### Added
 - Initial Craft 3 release
```

This was lifted directly from [Craft's documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/changelogs-and-updates.html#setting-up-a-changelog) on changelogs so I'm not sure what I'm missing. Is there anything else I can try or debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the Plugin Store hasn't picked up the 2.0.1 release is that you've got 3 different 2.0.1 tags in the repo.

[image]

Usually, that's not a problem as it will just pick the first one by date.

In this case, if you browse the first "V2.0.1" tag, you'll see that its composer.json file has a listed version of 2.0.0, which is a version mismatch, so the Plugin Store will ignore it. https://github.com/hillholliday/Craft-User-Manual/blob/00e2808e328e5bfe793fd343a59b5d2445d84d27/composer.json#L5

The reasons 2.0.2 never got picked up is because there is no 2.0.2 tag in the repo.

Comment: Thanks Brad, that makes perfect sense. I didn't realize the plugin store looked at git tags. I'll update accordingly.